# How to cache mapped data

Tags: java, caching

I need to cache the following data from DB for easy access:

Data is mapped as such: A, B and C are all objects with IDs. I will have a list of As, Bs and Cs such that:

- Many A is mapped to Many Bs
- Many B is mapped to Many Cs

I will be given an A and a C and will be asked to look up if the C falls in the given A.

I'm thinking I can have 2 caches

- ABCache: What are the Bs for A - 1:Many
- BCCache: what are the Cs for each B - 1:Many

One approach: I can loop through BCCache and find the B and then loop through ABCache to find A and then compare the given A.

Another approach: I can loop through ABCache and find all Bs and then loop through Bs to see if C falls in any Bs.

Is there any other better approach?

Comment: If this is the only lookup you need to make, you can also use an "ACCache". Inserting is a big more expensive, but in the end you need less memory and are faster to get results - especially if you sort the cache

Comment: And why don't you just use a big object which stores the A for every C? You can find out if C falls into A instantly.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description each `C` can be mapped to many `B`s and each `B` can be mapped to many `C`s and many `A`s, and each `A` can be mapped to many `B`s.

You could describe such a data as a graph, which practically allows almost any edge except from direct edge from `c` to `A` or vice versa.

Then, for any given `C` and `A` you can find if there is a path starting at this given `C` that passes through just one `B` to the given A.

One way to cache such data is to have a map of maps (or map of sets, if you only care if there's a path between `C` and `A` but don't care through which `B`) such that the key of the first map is `C` and the value is a map with a key of `A` to which it is connected and the value is the `B` which connects them.

If we talk code, it'll look as follows:

```
public class Cache<C, A> {

    Map<C, Set<A>> cache = new HashMap();

    public boolean isConnected(C c, A a) {
        if(cache.containsKey(c)) {
            if(cache.get(c).contains(a)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will work ok if your data is relatively static. If your data changes, then the overhead of updating the cache for every change in the data would be just too expensive.

**I personally think that a SQL query can be much more efficient than maintaining such a cache cache.**